# What is the difference Between '!:' and '?:' in TypeScript object definitions?

Tags: typescript, class, option-type

```js
Class Employee {
  firstName: string;
  lastName!: string;
  middleName?: string;
}
```

What is the difference in these 3 different fields of `Employee` class?

[Live Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/FAYwNghgzlAECiBbADmA9gTwKZdgb2FlgDMBLAJygBcA5CRLALlmvNIDsBzAbkNkmp0GAQmasOPPolIATGWCxCsAfjFU2XXnxBp2rAK4gqacgAoylWvSYt1EgJT4%20RKgAtSUAHQXB12AF4SCl8GXiIAX2BI4GJ9diNSXVgqLGpTRwIiHT0qWCwUdGxcQPYsAHcEAswcUwAiABVUqgla%20zDYbKg0BU90TlN81GqsNqjgYBS0%202AgA)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: Why not put the full code **in** the question (and fix the `Class`/`class` thing while you were at it)? Why only off-site?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type ORM '?' meaning in entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460693/type-orm-meaning-in-entities)

Answer (score 32):

**When having compiler option `strictNullChecks: false`**

If you have `strictNullChecks: false` in your `tsconfig.json` then they are exactly the same since having `strictNullChecks` disabled means that all fields can have null or undefined as valid values.

**When having compiler option `strictNullChecks: true`**

```
class Employee {
   firstName: string;
   lastName!: string;
   middleName?: string;
}
```

`firstName: string` means that `firstName` must be a `string`. `null` or `undefined` are not valid values for firstName.

All uninitialized fields will have a default value of `undefined`, so this will result in an error `Property 'firstName' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in constructor`

To silence the error you need to either change the declaration to `firstName: string = 'Some default value'` or add a constructor and assign a value for it in the constructor.

```
constructor() {
    this.firstName = 'some default value';
}
```

Now for the ! syntax. The `lastName!: string` syntax is similar to `lastName: string` in that it basically says that `string` is the only allowed type. `null` and `undefined` are not allowed. But it will silence the compiler about definite assignment error. Let's say you have the following code.

```
   class Employee {
       firstName: string;
       lastName!: string;
       middleName?: string;

      constructor() {
          // This will silence the compiler about first name not initialized
          this.firstName = 'some default value';
          // The compiler cannot tell that lastName is assigned in init() function
          this.init();
      }
      
      private init(): void {
          this.lastName = 'some default value';
      }
    }
```

In the previous code, `lastName` is definitely assigned in the `constructor` via the `this.init()` call. However, the compiler cannot know that. So adding the ! is basically telling the compiler *"shut up, I know what I am doing"*. It is up to you then to ensure the correctness of your code.

About the `middleName?: string` syntax. This is similar to `middleName: string | undefined`; Since all values has a default value of `undefined`, the compiler won't complain that `middleName` is not assigned.

Answer (score 20):

The `?` in that position [marks the property optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters).

The `!` in that position is the [definite assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions). It's sort of a declaration-level version of the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), but used on a property (can also be used on variables) rather than on an expression.

There are two — or arguably three — errors in that example:

1. `Class` should be `class`; JavaScript and TypeScript are case-sensitive.
2. You need an initializer on `firstName` (or a constructor that assigns to it unconditionally).
3. The `!` on `lastName` tells TypeScript that `lastName` will definitely be assigned, suppressing the kind of error you're getting for `firstName`, but nothing (in the example) actually *does* the assignment that using `!` there promises TypeScript you know for sure you're doing.

*Edit: The [code you linked](http://progressed%20with%20lies,) later deals with #1 and #2 above, but not #3. TypeScript won't warn that `lastName` is never assigned and assumes its value is a string, when in fact it's not there and so reading its value will result in `undefined`.*

Comment: What’s the difference between `lastName!: string;` and `declare lastName: string;`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [you can use `declare` inside a class](https://tsplay.dev/mqQKRm) as of TS3.7 [to support class field \[\[Define\]\] semantics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier).

Answer (score 5):

They are well hidden in the [documentation of TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html).

`?` is described on [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), it marks an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties).

`!` is the [definite assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions). It tells the compiler that the property is set (not `null` or `undefined`) even if TypeScript's analyses cannot detect so.

---

Btw, `Class` is not a TypeScript or JavaScript keyword and produces an error in that position. They keyword for declaring a class is `class`. TypeScript and JavaScript identifiers and keywords are case sensitive (`Class` and `class` are different things).